# uploading multiple images using the same button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i would like to know if its possible to upload multiple images using the same input. im having trouble uploading images i can only upload one and display it. and also would it be possible to make the background transparent

```js
// set up variables
var reader = new FileReader(),
    i=0,
    numFiles = 0,
    imageFiles;

// use the FileReader to read image i
function readFile() {
    reader.readAsDataURL(imageFiles[i])
}

// define function to be run when the File
// reader has finished reading the file
reader.onloadend = function(e) {
    
    // make an image and append it to the div
    var image = $('<img>').attr('src', e.target.result);
    $(image).appendTo('#images');
    
    // if there are more files run the file reader again
    if (i < numFiles) {
        i++;
        readFile();
    }
};

$('#go').click(function() {

    imageFiles = document.getElementById('files').files
    // get the number of files
    numFiles = imageFiles.length;
    readFile();           

});
```

```html
<input type="file" multiple="true" id="files" />
<button id="go" data-bind="click: addNew">Create</button>
<div id="images"></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/2.3.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script  
 src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script><script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/2.3.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet"
href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet"
 href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script src="http://circletype.labwire.ca/js/circletype.js"></script><script src="http://tympanus.net/Development/Arctext/js/jquery.arctext.js"></script>
```

Comment: _"i would like to know if its possible to upload multiple images using the same input."_ Yes, it is possible. Where at `js` are you experiencing an issue?  What is purpose of loading jQuery twice at `<script>` elements?

Comment: this code displays the first image but after that i cannot upload "display" the second image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.item()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList#item%20()) method of [`FileList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList) object to pass `File` object at index `i` to `readFile()`; set `i` to `0` at each click on `#go`

```js
// set up variables
var reader = new FileReader(),
  i = 0,
  numFiles = 0,
  imageFiles;

// use the FileReader to read image i
// pass `File` at index `i` within `FileList` to `readFile`
function readFile(file) {
  reader.readAsDataURL(file)
}

// define function to be run when the File
// reader has finished reading the file
reader.onloadend = function(e) {
  // increment `i`
  ++i;
  // make an image and append it to the div
  var image = $('<img>').attr('src', e.target.result);
  $(image).appendTo('#images');

  // if there are more files run the file reader again
  if (i < numFiles) {
    // pass `File` at index `i` within `FileList` to `readFile`
    readFile(imageFiles.item(i));
  } 
};

$('#go').click(function() {
  i = 0;
  imageFiles = document.getElementById('files').files
    // get the number of files
  numFiles = imageFiles.length;
  // pass first `File` to `readFile`
  readFile(imageFiles.item(i)); 

});
```

```html
<input type="file" multiple="true" id="files" />
<button id="go" data-bind="click: addNew">Create</button>
<div id="images"></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/2.3.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/2.3.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script src="http://circletype.labwire.ca/js/circletype.js"></script>
<script src="http://tympanus.net/Development/Arctext/js/jquery.arctext.js"></script>
```

Comment: @fidel Can you describe _"this is not working"_? What do you mean?

Comment: @fidel See updated post. Reset `i` to `0` at each click of `#go` element

Answer (score 0):

To enable multiple selections give the file input a name and make that name an array `name="files[]"` try:

```
<input name="files[]" type="file" multiple id="files" />
```

Comment: `multiple` attribute appears to be included at `html` at original Question `<input type="file" multiple="true" id="files" />`

Comment: I do believe a name attribute is required for this to work though

Comment: No `<form>` element is at `html` at Question; not certain about exactly how OP is currently uploading single file?

Comment: the FileReader api is just putting them on the page - they are not uploading anywhere by the looks of it...

Comment: i can only display one image i cannot display more

Comment: im going to upload the image to my database using php

Comment: sorry! no name attribute actually required to work in the browser only (but you might well need it for server processing) and running your example as-is but only using jQuery works fine http://jsbin.com/yisixuyoni/edit?html,js,output - the only thing I can assume is breaking it for you is either you are only selecting one file at a time (instead of using ctrl select in the file browser) or the data-bind attribute you have in your button is interfering with the process using another library e.g. knockout?